# DFS algorithm for forests

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, tree, depth-first-search

I am currently trying to implement a DFS algorithm able to work on forests. I have an adjacency matrix representing an MST. A much shorter version can be found below.

```
2   19
17  36
19  20
20  21
36  52
52  67
61  80
62  61
63  62
67  68
67  84
80  102
80  81
81  82
83  63
```

At first I tried using simple DFS but as expected it failed when the components were no longer connected. The main problem is that this is only one of many adjacency matrices I need to process. I read about placing  virtual root node per tree in the forest but this won't work because the adjacency matrix represents superpixels in an image and changes according to what is depicted. Thus I need help finding (if it exists) an algorithm able to detect the discontinuities and perform DFS per tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple: you've got a list of nodes. Just remove all nodes that were traversed by a single DFS-run from that list and start over with an arbitrary node of the list. Repeat this until the list is empty and you've traversed all trees.

Comment: Wow, that is so very simple and nice. I'll give it a shot and report back.

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thank you very much.